# Adding month not working as expected - Swift

Tags: swift, time

I am trying to add a month to a date. What I need to code that takes one date, and then returns that date as an object and also that date as an object + 1 month later. See my current code below:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/d"
stringDateMinimum = "2022-03-01"
let minimimDate = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDateMinimum)
print(minimimDate ?? "")       
var maximumDate =  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: minimimDate!)!
print(maximumDate)
```

I expected the output to be:

```
2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000
2022-04-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

But I actually got:

```
2022-03-01 00:00:00 +0000
2022-03-31 23:00:00 +0000
```

Could I think this could be because of the UK summer time as this problem only happens in march

Comment: `print(maximumDate.description(with: .current))`. Btw make sure to set the date formatter's calendar property before setting its timezone. This is even more important when you are not passing the time in your date string.

Comment: Yes, that is because of the DST transition, and because printing a `Date` always uses UTC. The second date *is* midnight of April 1 in your timezone.

Comment: Note that if you don't set the date formatter's calendar and the user device's calendar is set to Buddhist it will parse your date string year with more than 500 years offset.

Comment: Btw your date format should be dd instead of d  `"yyyy/MM/dd"`